# Value of post meta dropdown is not showing in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a select dropdown in my post meta in which I am getting post ids of all post of another custom post type. see below code-

```
    <select name="property_type" id="property_type">
               <option value=""></option>
             <?php
                $propertyType_args=array(
                  'post_type' => "soto_propertyType",
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  'posts_per_page' => -1,
                  'order' =>'ASC',
                  );

               $propertyType_query = null;
               $propertyType_query = new WP_Query($propertyType_args);
               if( $propertyType_query->have_posts() ) {
                  while ($propertyType_query->have_posts()) : $propertyType_query->the_post(); 
             ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" <?php selected( $property_type, the_ID(), false ); ?>><?php echo the_title(); ?></option>
            <?php
                  endwhile;
                }
                wp_reset_query(); 
              ?>
</select>
```

In this select list I am getting all ids of all post but not getting existing value as selected in option. I am getting select dropdown like this-

[image]

What I have to do to show existing value as selected in dropdown list.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_ID()` echoes its value, you can't use it in that context. Change it to [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).

Many functions in WordPress follow this pattern- one function will print, while the same function with `get_` prepended will [return](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) its value.

Comment: @shashank Please revisit this answer and accept it as it seems that the solution worked. :-)